# How to Make Timer by Integer(minute) in jquery?

Tags: jquery, timer

I have to make timer which have only minute and second. I just pass Integer number try to convert in minute but i failed.

`jquery` code is:-

```
 var start = 10;// 10 is minute
 i=1;
 setInterval(function() {
     $('#timing').text( ((start - i) % 60) + "Minute" + ((start - i) / 1000 ) +" Seconds");
     i++;

}, 1000);
```

hot can i do it? the timer is in decrements by second and then minute.

Comment: Homework? Set up a jsfiddle and we can help you through it.

Comment: ok sir. I am creating .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var start = 600;// 10 minutes
var i=1;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
     $('#timing').text( Math.floor((start - i) / 60) + " Minutes " + ((start - i) % 60 ) +" Seconds");
     i++;

    if(start === i) {
        window.clearInterval(timer);
        //DO STUFF HERE
    }

}, 1000);
```

I cleaned it up a tid for you. The `Math.floor` will make sure that the division is rounded down, making a nice clean display string for you. Also: the minutes is being held as number of seconds. You could change this easily if you wanted, just wasn't completely sure what your requirements are! Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Also, make sure you add cleanup logic to it! You don't want this running past 10 minutes (presumably):
if(i === start)
    window.clearInterval(myInterval);

Comment: Make sure you mark the question as answered if you are satisfied with everything!

Comment: sir if i have to stop doing something when timer is 00 . How can i handle this. basically i am creating the online examination project so that I required this.

Comment: updated to reflect cleaning up the timer. I added a comment to show where you should be doing stuff. Basically: When the number of increments, "i", is equal to the number of desired ticks, "start", we know that its time to clean up the interval and perform any other actions you need.

Comment: sir how to get 'myInterval' name of interval?

Comment: You have to set a name for the interval initially and then you'll be able to get it as @BrentEchols has done here with 'timer'.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another example - http://jsfiddle.net/pX5dd/

```
var minutes = 1;
var seconds = minutes * 60;

function convertIntToTime (num) {
    var mins = Math.floor(num/60);
    var secs = num % 60;
    var timerOutput = (mins < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + secs;
    return(timerOutput);
}

var countdown = setInterval(function() {
    var current = convertIntToTime(seconds); // set the display of the time
    $('.timer').html(current); // place the display time in the div
    if(seconds == 0) { 
        clearInterval(countdown); // stop the time if seconds = 0
        // other function calls here
    }
    seconds--; // subtract a second
}, 1000);
```

It is longer and not as compact as Brent's is, but it may give you a reusable function for time formatting. If you want to call another function when the timer runs out you can call it in the if statement.